# Do not hide dialog when focus lost in Android

Tags: android, android-dialog

My simple code here shows a Dialog in Android. I want to not hide the dialog when the user clicks outside the dialog or the dialog loses focus. How can I do it?

```
DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    switch (which) {
      case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "yes", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
      case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "no", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
      }
    }
  };
```

And the button code is:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setMessage("Are you sure?")
  .setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener)
  .setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener).show();
```

Thanks.

Comment: ur question is confusing... do u want to hide the dialog when u click outside ???

Comment: no i dont,i want to show the dialog when click outside.
in ths dialog when i click outside it hide.

Comment: still confusing.... can u explain properly

Comment: when I click a button then show this yes no dialog,but after show,if I click out side the dialog,it auto hide,but I want not to hide this,just like joptionpane dalog

Comment: as was in my answer use dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

Comment: would you please give a sample full code to do this

Comment: its just one line, in ur case builder.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use this for hiding if clicked outside  `dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);`

or use this for NOT hiding if clicked out side `dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);`

Answer (score 3):

Using `dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)` will prevent the Dialog from hiding only if the user clicks outside the box, but not if he clicks on the 'back' button on Android devices;

using `dialog.setCancelable(false)` will prevent both.

Answer (score 0):

This sample code is worked fine,

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
        dialog.setTitle("Title...");
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        dialog.show();
```